# jax return 0 if condition, continue if not in a jitted function

Tags: python, if-statement, jit, jax

I want to replicate this behaviour in a jitted function (the function is an example):

```
def function(x,y):
   if y==0:
      return x
   return x+1
```

Using `jax.lax.cond` it can be obtained with:

```
@jax.jit
def function(x,y):
   return jax.lax.cond(y==0, lambda x: x, lambda x: x+1, x)
```

This is simple as long as whatever needs to be done is simple when `y!=0` (in this case, just add `1` to `x`). However, if that's complex, or there are more conditions of this sort, coding gets more convoluted.

Is there a way to get the behavior "if `y==0`, return `x`, if not, just keep running the function. `jax.lax.cond` requires a *new* function for every condition that is applied.

For example, this starts to become convoluted.

```
def function(x,y):
    if y==0:
       return x
    if y>0:
       return x-y
    if y<0:
       return x+y
```

This starts to be messy:

```
@jax.jit
def function(x,y):
    jax.lax.cond(y==0, 
             lambda x,y: x, 
             lambda x,y: jax.lax.cond(x>0, lambda x,y:x-y, lambda x,y: x+y, x,y),
             x,y)
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no, there's no way to return early from a Python function conditioned on traced values. The pattern I typically see to avoid messy nesting is to encapsulate logic in helper functions and call them via `lax.cond`.

Alternatively, if you are branching based on multiple conditions, you may be able to better express the logic in terms of [`lax.switch`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.lax.switch.html); for example:

```py
@jax.jit
def function(x, y):
  branches = [lambda: x, lambda: x-y, lambda: x+y]
  conditions = jnp.array([y == 0, x > 0, True])
  return lax.switch(jnp.argmax(conditions), branches)
```